# spritekitでのタッチイベント

Tags: ios

簡単なゲームの作成でにおいて、つくったノード（敵）をタッチイベントで消したいんですが、やり方がわかりません。よろしくお願いします。

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    // マルチタッチを有効にする
    self.view?.multipleTouchEnabled = true

    // 一つの情報を取り出します
    for touch in touches {
        // シーン上の位置をとりだします
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        // その位置にあるノードをしらべる
        let touchNodes = self.nodesAtPoint(location)
        // ノードひとつひとつを調べる
        for tNode in touchNodes {
            // タッチしたノードが敵なら消す
            if tNode == mySprite
            {
                mySprite.removeFromParent()

                // 位置を表示する
                print(tNode)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`removeFromParent()`だけで、ノードは消えます。
ご提示のコードで消えないのなら、提示のない箇所に問題があるのだと考えられます。

※質問の重複を解消するには、他方の質問を削除するだけでなく、他方を残して、こちらを削除するという方法も考えられます。